# Prove $\lim_{x\to\frac{5\pi}{3}}\cos{x}$ using the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of a limit

Tags: limits, proof-writing

How does one prove
$$\lim_{x\to\frac{5\pi}{3}}\cos{x} = \frac{1}{2}$$
using the epsilon-delta definition of a limit?

I have tried to follow the following train of thought for hours:

$$\left|\frac{1}{2}-\cos{x}\right|<\epsilon$$
Multiply left side by 1:
$$\left|\frac{\frac{1}{4}-\cos^2{x}}{\frac{1}{2}+\cos{x}}\right|<\epsilon$$
$$\left|\frac{\sin^2{x}-\frac{3}{4}}{\frac{1}{2}+\cos{x}}\right|<\epsilon$$
$\sin^2{x}\leq x$ for all $|x|$
and so on, but I can't seem to get anywhere.

Comment: You are allowed to say $\frac 12 = cos \frac {5\pi}{3}$

Comment: $\cos x = \cos (\frac{5 \pi}{3} + (x - \frac{5 \pi}{3})) = \cos (\frac{5\pi}{3}) \cos (x - \frac{5 \pi}{3}) - \sin (\frac{5\pi}{3}) \sin (x - \frac{5\pi}{3})$, so $|\cos x - \cos \frac{5\pi}{3}| \le \cos (\frac{5\pi}{3}) |\cos (x - \frac{5\pi}{3}) - 1| - \sin (\frac{5\pi}{3}) |\sin (x - \frac{5\pi}{3}) |$ (the minus sign being because $\sin (\frac{5\pi}{3}) < 0$).  Now make the first absolute value less than $\epsilon / (2 \cos (\frac{5\pi}{3}))$ and similarly for the second absolute value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$|\cos x - \frac 12|\\
|\cos x - \cos \frac {5\pi}{3}|\\
\cos a - \cos b = 2\sin(\frac {a+b}{2})\sin(\frac {b-a}{2})\\
|2\sin (\frac {\frac {5\pi}{3}-x}{2})\sin (\frac {x+\frac {5\pi}{3}}{2})|\\  
\forall y, |\sin y| \le |y|\\
|2\sin (\frac {\frac {5\pi}{3}-x}{2})|\le |\frac {5\pi}{3}-x|\\
|\sin (\frac {x+\frac {5\pi}{3}}{2})|\le 1\\
|\cos x - \frac 12| \le  \delta$

let $\delta = \epsilon, |x - \frac {5\pi}{3}|\implies |\cos x - \frac 12|<\epsilon$

Comment: So knowing $|sin(x)| \le |x|$ and you can show cos continuous everywhere.